# Genus 2 3-manifolds bounding only $X^4$ with $b_2(X^4)$ big?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

The genus of a closed orientable  3-manifold $M^3$ is the minimum genus among all Heegaard splitting surfaces for $M$.  Every such 3-manifold bounds a compact 4-manifold.  Let $I(M)$ denote the minimum second Betti number $b_2$ amongst all such bounding $X^4$.

Is there a sequence of genus 2 3-manifolds $M_n$ such that $I(M_n) \to \infty$.

Comment: Do you know any sequence of $M_n$ such that $I(M_n)--> \infty $?

Comment: @Mukherjee I do not but I have a faint memory of seeing a lower bound for $I(M)$ somewhere.  It probably was not called $I(M)$ though.

Comment: It will be great if you can recall a source for that. I am not able to think of such examples.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think one can get a Kirby diagram for a bounding manifold consisting of genus component $0$-framed unlink and multiple $\pm 1$ framed unknots unlinked from each other. Then one can eliminate the $\pm 1$ framed unknots by a Kirby move. So the answer is no. There is a description of this diagram, for example, in "A simple proof of the fundamental theorem of Kirby calculus on links" by Ning Lu.

Comment: @mathquest I didn;t get your comment. What are you trying to prove/state here?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I was saying, that it seems that for a genus $n$-manifold one can get a bounded by it $4$-manifold with just $1$ $0$-handle, $n$ $2$-handles and no other handles. As for your question - I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I think it follows that a Heegaard genus 2 manifold will bound a topological 4-manifold with $b_2\leq 2$ from a theorem of Steve Boyer.

*Boyer, Steven*, [**Simply-connected 4-manifolds with a given boundary**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2000623), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 298, 331-357 (1986). [ZBL0615.57008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0615.57008). [MR0857447](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=857447)

I'm guessing that you're interested in the smooth category though?

Comment: If we don't restrict it to just genus 2, do you know any sequence M_n, such that this limit will be infinity, i.e my first comment in the comment section. (In smooth category).

Comment: Infact starting with any manifold, we can consider one of it's open book with connected binding. Then by doing a zero surgery,i.e, adding a 0 framed 2 handle in 4 dim version we can construct a surface bundle over circle. Now the question is, can we say anything about such special class? If it is trivial bundle, then we can conclude something.

Comment: I'm not sure - one can get lower bounds on bounding simply-connected manifolds in terms of $rank(H_1(M))$, but I don't think this gives a lower bound on $b_2$ of non-simply connected bounding manifolds.

Comment: @IanAgol: indeed, it doesn't give a lower bound in the non-simply connected case; e.g. just take a boundary connected sum of N copies of any rational homology 4-ball (like $T^*\mathbb{RP}^2$).

Comment: @IanAgol Yeah I was primarily interested in the smooth case - but I'm also happy to hear about the topological case.  Which theorem in Boyer's paper were you looking at?

Comment: I don’t have the paper in front of me right now, but the idea is to do surgery to kill the homology. Then a homology sphere bounds a contractile 4-manifold.